# How to create video live using pictureBox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to create video live to view screen of another PC use `PictureBox` in C#. can I find the best way to solve this prolem. I Thank all.

Comment: from screen of nother PC! i buid the remote Desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/04a71252-bc81-4378-ac3e-129b46b74788/how-can-i-display-live-video-in-c-without-any-freezing-or-delay).

If you are using the following ctor:

Bitmap(int width, int height, int stride, PixelFormat format, IntPtr scan0)

then building the bitmap is a very lightweight operation, otherwise it can be more or less inefficient when wrapping a native buffer.

Bitmap itself uses GDI+, which uses DirectDraw, so it is quite fast. But I believe the real bottleneck here is the PictureBox, which is designed for static images, not live video. You should draw the images yourself using System.Drawing.Graphics.

and i guess that [site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/222620/how-can-i-save-a-live-image-from-picturebox-in-windowx-appli.aspx) would help you better.

Comment: so. i should use Graphics to create video?

Comment: You may actually first try it using a Panel. If that doesn't work for you, you may try to subclass Panel, override OnPaint event and draw bitmap there:

Comment: for e.g,: protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
`{
  if(this.bitmap != null && this.bitmapLocation != Point.Empty)
  {
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.bitmap , this.bitmapLocation);
  }
}`

Comment: OK. i will try it. I'm working to build a remote desktop application!

Comment: i want to use socket to send client's creen to my PC to create living video. your link is difficult for me to understand. i'm beginer about c#.net!